# GXT Number field with percentFormat multiply my value itself to 100

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using GXT NumberField for GXT TextField.
all works ok ,i.e I see % symbol and can input any number , 
But because of Percent default behavior it multiply it with 100 and the value of Textfield changes .

I just want to display the same number entered by user,(not multiply by 100).
I see some solution using DecimalFormat , and changing the multiplier value to 1, But DecimalFormat dont work at client side ,

any idea What can i do

```
public class PercentField extends NumberField<Integer>{
public PercentField (NumberPropertyEditor<Integer> editor) {
    super(editor);

}
protected NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentFormat();
public final static String percentSymbol;

static{

    percentSymbol= "%";

}

{
    numberFormat.overrideFractionDigits(0, 0);
    numberFormat = NumberFormat.getFormat("%" + percentSymbol);
}
```

i made this above class, and extend my textfield from this.

Comment: Can you please post the sample code you have tried?

Comment: code sample added